# Mounting hangs the terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I am creating a NFS share. I've configured the NFS server and also the NFS client.

My share was working perfectly fine until yesterday and now I found out it doesn't work.

I redid all the steps of NFS configuration and it still doesn't work.

My problem is that when I try to access my mount folder using `cat /mnt/nfs1.txt` (which was working perfectly fine until yesterday), nothing appears on the screen. And it looks like it is hanged or it collapsed.

```
root@ela-native:~# cat /mnt/nfs1.txt
```

After this nothing appears on the screen and also I have to close the terminal to quit.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1**

The following are the steps in my configurations for the nfs:

NFS server:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

sudo mkdir /var/nfs/general

sudo nano /etc/exports

  /var/nfs/general *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

sudo exportfs -a

sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
```

NFS client:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common

sudo mount 172.21.215.101:/var/nfs/general /mnt
```

And also if i run `mount -t nfs`, i get this:

```
root@ela-native:/home/salini# mount -t nfs
172.21.215.101:/var/nfs/general on /mnt type nfs (rw,vers=4,addr=172.21.215.101,clientaddr=192.168.164.78)
```

I also tried `showmount -e 172.21.215.101` i got

`clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out`

**Edit2**

And the i tried `less /var/log/boot.log` in the server machine and according to my understanding, i think that there is some error with the nfs server.

```
[ESC[0;1;31mFAILEDESC[0m] Failed to start Automatically refresh installed snaps.


 [ESC[0;1;31mFAILEDESC[0m] Failed to mount /mnt/nfs/var/nfs.
    See 'systemctl status mnt-nfs-var-nfs.mount' for details.
   [ESC[0;1;33mDEPENDESC[0m] Dependency failed for Remote File Systems.
             Starting Permit User Sessions...
             Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
             Starting LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand"...
             Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
             Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
             Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
             Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
    [ESC[0;32m  OK  ESC[0m] Mounted /mnt/nfs/home.
```

What is the problem here?

**Edit3**

I did `sudo ufw status numbered` and `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111`. I got this:

```
root@wsm-ela-inc6:/home/test# sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 514/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 514/udp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 514/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 4] 514/udp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

root@wsm-ela-inc6:/home/test# sudo netstat -nlp | grep :111
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3062/rpcbind    
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      3062/rpcbind    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           3062/rpcbind    
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                3062/rpcbind
```

**Edit4**

I did :

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 2049

sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 111
```

And I tried again for `showmount` but then again the terminal give me this

`clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out`

Also I tried `sudo service portmap restart` and i got `portmap: unrecognized service`. Also i tried `sudo service statd restart`, it went well. Then again i tried `showmount` but still the same problem.

Now that I've did `umount`, I couldn't do `mount`. The terminal just hangs!!

Help please.

Comment: Turn off the firewalls on both server and client, and try again from scratch.  If that fixes things, you've narrowed down the problem a lot.

Comment: OMG!! Thank You @MadHatter. I disabled the firewalls on both the client and the server. And now it works wonderful.. Thank you soo much... :) :) :)

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer so that you can accept it, and thus put the question to bed, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried disabling the firewalls on server and client, and it's all sprung into life.  Generally, if client and server are not on the same trusted network, running NFS between them isn't a great idea - not least because it doesn't play with dumb firewalls very well.  If client and server are on the same trusted network, then a more blanket permit on each system for input traffic from the other will probably keep things working.